# cannot connect flutter apk in another wifi

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

i like to know that anybody can help me with my flutter problem
i build an app with a ip adress to connect with database localhost ,
i already build the apk and give it to my friend to test my app
in my case is i cannot connect flutter apk in another wifi , but on my wifi the app can running .

there's anybody can help me how to connect flutter apk  with global ip so my app can running at what ever connection's  is

sorry for my bad english

#flutter can't connect to another ipadreesshi

how to conncet my apk with gobal ip so everybody can use my app

Comment: because it hosted in localhost . if you buy a hosting then it will work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i see thank you for teh answer